# How to retrieve data from database and display it in a table format through PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, web

Well, I've been working on retrieving the data based on only the Regno and Subcode provided through GET method.

I did try out the getting output without the table format , just by using printf stmt .

```
<?php
            $regNo=$_GET['Regno'];
            $Subjectcode=$_GET['Subjectcode'];
```

( then there is the connection part )

```
$sql="SELECT Co1,Co2, Co3, Co4, Co5, Co6 FROM ab where Regno='$regNo' and 
Subcode='$Subjectcode'";
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);



            // Associative array
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            ?>
            <div>
                <table >
                <tr>
                    <th>Co1</th>
                    <th>Co2</th>
                    <th>Co3</th>   // these get displayed 
                    <th>Co4</th>
                    <th>Co5</th>
                    <th>Co6</th>
                </tr>

                <?php
                If (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                <tr>    
                        <td><?php echo $row['Co1']; ?></td> 
                        <td><?php echo $row['Co2']; ?></td> 
                        <td><?php echo $row['Co3']; ?></td>  // these don't get displayed
                        <td><?php echo $row['Co4']; ?></td> 
                        <td><?php echo $row['Co5']; ?></td> 
                        <td><?php echo $row['Co6']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    }
                    ?>

                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
```

The output should be the data displayed in the table format . but the output I've been getting is just nothing !!!

EDIT 1

I've also tried this code

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);  

// 1. Enter Database details
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'all';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}  

$reg_no = isset($_POST['Regno']) ? $_POST['Regno'] : '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ab WHERE Regno='".$reg_no."'";

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
     $Sem = $rows['Sem'];
     $Co1 = $rows['Co1'];
     $Co2 = $rows['Co2'];
     $Co3 = $rows['Co3'];
     $Co4 = $rows['Co4'];
     $Co5 = $rows['Co5'];
     $Co6 = $rows['Co6'];
     $Subname = $rows['Subname'];
     $Externalmarks = $rows['Externalmarks'];

     echo 


 "$Subname<br>$Sem<br>$Co1<br>$Co2<br>$Co3<br>$Co4<br>$Co5<br>$Co6<br>
 $Externalmarks<br><br>";  

 } 

 ?>
```

[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrNSC.png)

Comment: What do you see when you look at the HTML source, do you see `<?php echo $row['Co1']; ?>` (etc.) as code like that?

Comment: First of all, have you tested that SQL sentence manually in the DB to see how many and which results do you get? Second, why you fetch the result twice? (The first time casting to an associative array and the second time not. Why not simply loop the associative array instead of making a while and again fetching the results?

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner  Nope, it's just blank

Comment: @Osakr Yep , cuz I did use while and tried to fetch but I get an error

Comment: Could you do a var_dump($row); after the first fetch and see what returns. If the data is there you just have to do a foreach and put the html in there

Comment: @Osakr In vain ! Can you please check my Edit .....

Comment: What do you mean with in vain? Nothing was returned by the var_dump ¿? Also in your edit you forgot to do the mysql query

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @Osakr please help !!

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so in your edit you are not using mysqli_query() before passing the SQL into the mysqli_fetch_array() so it is not going to return any results.

Here is some reference materials:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);  

// 1. Enter Database details
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'all';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}  
// Get the variable needed for the query. URL should look like ex: something.com/thispage.php?Regno=1220
$reg_no = isset($_GET['Regno']) ? $_GET['Regno'] : ''; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ab WHERE Regno='" . $reg_no . "'";
$query = $conn->query($sql);

?>

<div>
    <table >
        <tr>
            <th>Co1</th>
            <th>Co2</th>
            <th>Co3</th>
            <th>Co4</th>
            <th>Co5</th>
            <th>Co6</th>
        </tr>
<?php
    // Place each result into an array.
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    // Loop through the array and structure the table.
    foreach($rows as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Co1'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Co2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Co3'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Co4'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Co5'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Co6'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    // Free the result set. 
    $query->close();

    // Close the connection. 
    $conn->close();
 ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: "SELECT * FROM ab WHERE Regno=''" Isn't the actual query you are using is it? I seriously doubt you made a table called AB. Can you show us the table and what you are trying to query in your question? @Jay

Comment: I'm sure I'm using ab and not AB . I've also included a pic in my edit , just check @Colton Wagner